# Idfix: Cannot handle multi-forest?

Tags: microsoft-dfo365

In preparation for Office 365, I have downloaded Idfix to run against my Active Directory to clean up any duplicate or incorrect attributes.

Because I plan to migrate 2x AD forest (a.com and b.com with interforest trust and selective authentication NOT forest-wide authentication) into 1x single Azure tenant, I thought I will need to run Idfix against the 2x forest at the same time so that it could find out if there are any conflicts.  However, I found out so far that Idfix cannot handle multi-forest (while I think multi-domain with the same forest can).

[image]

Can someone who have gone through multi-forest migration to Azure give me some feedback?
And if I really cannot use Idfix to clean up the objects before migration, is there a way to do it manually?

Much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the gear icon and go into settings, you will see the local domain you are logged onto by default in the Active Directory section.  You can type in the FQDN for the additional domain in the box below and click "Add" to include the additional domain/forest.  Of course, the account you are logged in with will need to have appropriate permissions for both directories or you can supply credentials for an account that has the appropriate credentials in that same settings page.  when you run the tool, you should see information for both domains and any conflicts that the tool finds.